# What happened to the "chat room" link?

Tags: support, status-completed, links

There was a link to both meta and the chat room near the top of the page before, and it seems to have disappeared. Is there going to be a permanent link added back to the main page / menu bar thingy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that menu bar thingy (system message) is going to be removed from permanent display, and only appear when there are actual important system messages, as otherwise people just tend to ignore it.

I think once per site chat rolls out, there will be a 'chat' link up next to 'meta'/'parent'.  Until then the only link is in the chatroom faq post, but this should be featured on the main site in the new featured meta posts bit on the right.

Comment: Already been removed - I did it last night. :)  This is otherwise exactly right though; if the chat link is always in the "system message" box then it means people will probably ignore messages that are *actually* critical.  At least according to Jeff/Robert, one of the main reasons they implemented the meta "ads" on the parent site was so we wouldn't *need* to use the system message area for "interesting" links.

Comment: Yes, the link I was referring to was in the system message. And by "menu bar thingy" I actually meant the bar containing the meta/parent link, logout, profile, about, faq, etc.

Answer (score 1):

cooking.stackexchange now has a chat home on [chat.stackexchange](http://chat.stackexchange.com/); the "chat" option is now at the top of every Q&A page.

You aren't limited to 1 room - feel free to use chat for all (sensible) cooking chat-related purposes.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the chat room (as I was) in the mean time, [get to it from here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252/the-frying-pan):

- http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252/the-frying-pan